# Accessing interpolated value from inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following simple directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp').directive('readonlyList', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'list.html',
        scope: {
            selectedNumber: '=',
            numbers: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch('numbers', function() {

                for(var i=0; i < $(element).children().length; i++) {
                    console.log("list entry text: " + $(element).children().eq(i).text());
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

With the following template:

```
<ul class="no-bullet phone-list scrollable">
    <li ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number}}</li>
</ul>
```

However running the code I get the following:

**{{number}}**

**{{number}}**

**{{number}}**

I've tried compiling the code just before the for loop:

```
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

That generates multiple duplicates in my list.

I'm using angular 1.3...

I'm a bit lost here, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And how do you use directive in your code?

Comment: @Engineer in html it is simply `<readonly-number-list selected-number="obj.number" numbers="numberList.numbers"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch block is executed in the same digest loop as Angular ngRepeat rendering, so items are not yet processed by Angular.

Probably simplest thing is to run `$watch` code in the next digest cycle. You can achieve it using `$timeout` service:

```
scope.$watch('numbers', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $timeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $(element).children().length; i++) {
            console.log("list entry text: " + $(element).children().eq(i).text());
        }
    });
});
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LRWogLk6IRw5TCHB8bp1?p=preview